# Restrict High Chart to show original value rather than average for range selector

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using high charts line graph with multiple range selectors options such as 10 minutes, 1 day, 1 week, 3 weeks, 1 month, 3 months, 6 months till 5 years. The problem is for some range selector options the value displayed on the chart is not accurate, I understand from the documentation that it calculates average.
I am using data grouping as 'false' and approximation 'close' but still the for some selectors it calculates average.

for example:
For this one date '1 Dec 2020' It shows different values.

Range selector All: 26.28

Range selector 5 years: 26.28

Range selector 6 months: 26.4

What I want is to restrict the high chart to show the average if points are close and instead show one true value. So if there 5 points closer to each other instead of showing their average just show one original.

OR Is it possible to show one point from each data group instead of an average of that group?

How can I achieve this?
The data displayed needs to be very accurate.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `dataGrouping.approximation` feature to implement your own function which calculates and shows only first values? API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation

Comment: Yes, but it isn't working probably the data groups are not accessible, or maybe I am doing something wrong not sure.

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt on some online editor which I could debug?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Look at this example, I have disabled data grouping so when I select data from the range selector till 1 yr it shows accurate data(Original values). However, When I select 5 years then API explicitly makes data groups thus showing averages. What I would like is to show 1st value from each data group.
https://jsfiddle.net/wislam/zt9fe4x0/13/

Comment: Waqa ul islam, take a look at this demo and test the '1 yr' button. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4vjs8zxe/ is this a wanted output?